# AJAX recommendations for newbie

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to do a little bit of AJAX.

- Autocomplete
- Favourites (in the same style as SO - clicking a star toggles an entry's favouriteness)

I know hardly anything about client-side scripting - I am a Java programmer by trade.

What library would allow me to do what I want without it being overkill? I have a feeling that jQuery would fit the bill, but I have no idea whether that is already too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jquery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). As far as favorites are concerned, there are [many plugins](http://www.enfew.com/5-best-jquery-star-rating-plugins-tutorials/) out there.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the way to go. It became an de-facto industry standard and you will find code examples for pretty much everything. Another poster already suggested the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget, so lets see about the "favorite" functionality.

Lets imagine that you have a PHP script that generates an HTML list that contains some text and an "id" for every element of the list, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="item4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Then you have a file on your server that given an `action` will do something with an `id`.
With jQuery and a little CSS (class "starred") you could do something like this:

```
jQuery('li').bind("click",function(){
    var current = jQuery(this);
    var action = "add";
    if(current.hasClass("starred")){
        action = "remove";
    }
    jQuery.ajax("favorite.php",{
        type:"POST",
        data:{action:action,id:current.attr('id')},
        onSuccess: function(){
            current.toggleClass("starred");
        }
    });
})
```

Full working example (minus server-side script):

http://jsfiddle.net/hbCz8/3/